# Getting suitable eventHandler after GetInvocationList()

Tags: c#, wcf, delegates, event-handling, handler

I have

```
public delegate void AdministrationEventHandler(object sender, AdministrationEventArgs e);
public static event AdministrationEventHandler MainAdministrationEventHandler;
```

It's main event handler in my wcf service.
I have also

```
private void MyEventHandler(object sender, AdministrationEventArgs e)
{
//code
}
```

I add new element

```
AdministrationEventHandler userToAddEventHandler = new AdministrationEventHandler(MyEventHandler);
```

and then

```
MainAdministrationEventHandler += userToAddEventHandler;
```

In my `Broadcast()` method I call `MyEventHandler` to each handler. 
I'd like to call `Broadcast()` according to the `AdministrationEventArgs e` argument.

I tried to make something like list of `MainAdministrationEventHandler` and call `Broadcast()` for appropiate element of this list, but it doesn't work.

I'm getting all handlers by `MainAdministrationEventHandler.GetInvocationList()`

**Is it possible** to check `e` argument after getting it in `GetInvocationList()`?

Or **how can I in other way** call `Broadcast()` to suitable handlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's a suitable handler? Because based on your code you can only assign handlers of type `AdministrationEventHandler` to that event.

Also, the list returned from `GetInvocationList()` only contains the handlers to invoke. They haven't been invoked yet this time around, and you need to invoke them and pass `e` to them.

Something like this should do:

```
AdministrationEventArgs args = new AdministrationEventArgs();
Delegate[] dels = MainAdministrationEventHandler.GetInvocationList();
if (dels != null)
    foreach (Delegate handler in dels)
        handler.Invoke(this, args);
```

Comment: E.g. I have 3 different AdministrationEventArgs. One for each AdministrationEventHandler. Now I want in foreach loop to see them, and Invoke on 2 of 3 handlers. Is it possible?

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding events in .Net. Here is a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx). Take a look at Example 1, the `OnChanged()` method. Each event invocation gets the same `AdministrationEventArgs` instance. If you want to do different things based on the information in the `AdministrationEventArgs` you should assign 1 handler and put an if statement in it.

Comment: If this is the answer to your question, can you please mark it as such? Thanks.

Comment: It's complicated :) Its'n not answer to my question, because I found other solution. But you aim me to some direct, also let's assume, it is acctable answer :)